# Profile and Privacy

Tags: discussion

I used facebook to setup my account. It shows my full name. 
I want to be able to change it to a nickname or pseudonym.

Also, I want to be able to change the profile picture.

Comment: This will hopefully get migrated to the right place for asking questions about the site shortly. In the meantime, [go here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/edit/59756) and edit as you wish.

Comment: And then delete this question, so that you're further protected

Comment: Thanks today is my first day using StackExchange.

Comment: @ZachLipton Done.

Comment: @Dorothy I made the correction. I think that this question will be useful to others. I will leave it.

Comment: @AlphaTraveler Welcome!

Comment: @ZachLipton By the way, when I saw the meta open up to me I thought it was unrelated to travel and specifically related to the parent website layout,features,  UI, UX and so on.